# Clear all arrays inside given JObject

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

I require to clear/empty all arrays inside a given JObject. Is there a better way to achieve this.

```
var jobject = request.selectToken(keyPath) as JObject;
foreach (var token in jobject.Descendants().Where(jt => jt is JArray).ToList())
{
   var referenceToken = token as JArray;
   referenceToken.Clear();                     
}
```

I also tried reassigning **referenceToken = new JArray()**, but this of course gives compilation errors.

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: Do you need to recurse down in the `JObject` or just the top level properties? What is wrong with your existing code? You could maybe improve it with `foreach (var array in jobject.Descendants().OfType<JArray>()) array.Clear();`

Comment: No just the root level tokens. I came up with this code adhoc just want to be sure if its according to best practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `ToList`. And you can also remove the type-check by using `OfType`

```cs
foreach (var array in jobject.Descendants().OfType<JArray>())
    array.Clear();
```

If you only need root-level properties which are arrays then you can instead use `jobject.Children()` which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to remove the whole item, not just to clean an item value.

```
    jobject.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Any(x => x.Type == JTokenType.Array))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(tr => tr.Remove());
```